# get logs of login and logout of windows users

Tags: c#, windows

i want to write a win program and i want to save logs of login and logout of any users(such as time ,username,date,...) that use my pc in every day ,but maybe my application isn't run?can i get this log file from OS??if yes how??
please help and guide me.thanks.

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: it's not fix.now it is xp(servise pack2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write an application for this - all this information is already logged into the [Windows Security Log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Security_Log) (which you can view with the built in event viewer).

You can use WMI to query these logs, or directly with the [`EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) class (though you will need quite high privileges to do so).

Comment: Well, he/she says it's his/her PC, so privileges shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, someone should move this question to Super User.

Comment: @Oded:if i shutdown my pc,this information will being clear??

Comment: @Niklas Bergius - assumptions, assumptions. Regardless, it always makes sense to mention extra privilege requirements. And Since this is tagged C#, I assumed this is a programming question.

Comment: @na.fa - No, it will not. It will only clear when the log is manually cleared (or if it is setup to rollover and remove old entries).

Comment: @Oded:if i have 10 users that use my pc,every one with his username and password,i can have information about all users??thanks for your attention.

Comment: @na.fa - Yes. Perhaps you should read the wikipedia article I linked to.